# How can Naruto characters teleport/disappear?

Tags: naruto

In the manga/anime, it appears as if teleportation is very rare. The few we know that gets a little bit explained are, for example, Minato (4th Hokage) and Obito (Tobi).

Despite of this, a lot of characters (mainly in the anime) "disappear" with a flashy exit when they wish. Orochimaru does this a couple of times, including others. Often with a phrase such as "I don't have time to play around with you any more" and then *poof*, gone!

Is there some explanation to this? Do they use a clone and then run off while the clone says goodbye to the opponent? If that is the case, when do they create the clone?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From what I understand, there are only actually a few ways to teleport. Those include Tobirama/Minato's Flying Thunder God technique, reverse summoning, and Obito's space/time Sharingan based technique.

Most of the time, when shinobi just poof, that means it was either a clone or they travel at a high speed such that one can not detect their movements. If it was a clone, then it was always a clone to begin and the person did not just substitute himself for a clone.

Comment: Kakashi got a book from Jiraiya then he went to read it, he just poofed away just like a shadow clone, so if it was a clone, how did the clone carry the book away back to the original? Sasuke kabuto and Orochimaru just burned away when they found them at the hideout, we all know they weren't clones. The fast movement you mentioned did happen multiple times and they use different visual and audio effects for it. Reverse summoning would be an explanation but then who does reverse summon them and how do they know when to summon them? and how we never saw a hand sign for substitution :D

Answer (score 1):

They're ninjas!  They're so sneaky that they can sneak away and leave a log or some object behind and it only looks like they've teleported.